# Clear Validation errors from ViewModel class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, viewmodel

**Problem:**

I have 2 DateTime objects (start date and end date) on my GUI. I have implemented **IDateErrorInfo** to display error if start date is greater than end date, and vice versa

If I then select an end date that is further smaller then start date then error is displayed on that box. At this point both dates display error.

[Image of above description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOKqn.png)

If I then rectify this by setting start date smaller than end date then the error is removed from start date but end date still displays error (until I manually click and change to remove it).

How can I remove the error on end date, when start date is modified to be less than end date?

[Adding modified for clarification]

```
public class MainWindowModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
        ....
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        ....

   public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {                
            string result = null;
            if (columnName == nameof (StartDate))
            {
                result = _contentFactory.ValidateDateTimes(StartDate.Ticks, EndDate.Ticks);
                // Need to clear error on end date.
                if (result == null)
                {    
                     // How to get control of EndDate to populate method below ???
                     Validation.ClearInvalid( ???? );                        

                }
            }
            if (columnName == nameof(EndDate))
            {
                result = _contentFactory.ValidateDateTimes(StartDate.Ticks, EndDate.Ticks);
                if (result == null)
                {     
                       // How to get control name of StartDate.
                      Validation.ClearInvalid( ???? )                                                      
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**What I have achieved so far:**
I have tried to use Validation.ClearInvalid but that requires the control name. This is not available in the View model class. So I have to setup an action (event) from ViewModel which is then implemented in code behind XAML class to access the control directly.

Another way is mentioned is link below to use a Visual tree to search for the field.
[WPF Validation: Clearing all validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148064/wpf-validation-clearing-all-validation-errors)

I am not satisfied with either of methods.

Is there a better way.

Many thanks.

Comment: Please add some code to give us some context on your question.

Comment: Updated above description

Comment: If the result is proper then update the prop like on onpropertychanged("StartDate") simple.

Comment: @AvinashReddy I tried that. When you call OnPropertyChanged it calls the method `string this[string columnName]` again, and thus it recursively calls itself again infinitely.

Comment: u can write like this then If(StartDate>EndDate){ OnPropertyChanged ("startdate")  return error;  }

Comment: @AvinashReddy That still gives the same problem.